# How can Hot Spots be cleared?

Tags: flash-point

In the advanced version of the rules for the Flash Point board game, there are Hot Spots which cause Flare-ups when targeted in the Advance Fire roll.
**How are the players supposed to get rid of a hot spot?** I haven't found a specific mention of it in the rules, so I just assumed it is removed when the fire and smoke in the given square are completely extinguished.

I have checked the official web, but the rule explanations there are only available for the Family/casual difficulty setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't found an official answer to this question yet, I played the game some more and it seems to me that it is more in the spirit of the game to leave the hot spot in place, even after putting the flames out.

Considering that there can only be a limited number of new hot spots (placed via flare-ups) - 6 for all difficulties except Heroic, where it is 12 - it seemed too easy to just get rid of them quickly.
Also, when placing additional hot spots at the beginning of the game, they can be placed on open spaces without fires; therefore it seems to make sense for them to remain even after the fire is extinguished.

**Edit**: Neal Tibrewala confirmed in the comments that there really is no way of removing them. (Thanks.)

Comment: There is no way to remove them.  There have been rumors of an expansion adding character cards with that ability.

Answer (score 7):

The [Urban Structures](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/110139/flash-point-fire-rescue-urban-structures) expansion contains a role that allows you to remove hotspots:

[image: Structural Engineer Role Card]

Comment: This guy can fix a hole the size of a door in one turn?! ...and he's a fireman who doesn't know how to extinguish fire?! The expansions for this game have the most horrible rules. I'm really disappointed with all the ones I've seen so far.